# merge the data of two eloquent models into an independent array

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am working with laravel and I have basically these 3 related models in the following way: person model (Person.php), task model (Task.php) and post model (Post.php).

**Person.php**

```
public function tasks()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
}

public function posts()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

**Task.php**

```
public function person()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Person::class);
}
```

**Post.php**

```
public function person()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Person::class);
}
```

this is the way in which the models are related, now I have a method to recover a person and their tasks and posts that looks like this:

```
Person::with(['tasks','posts'])->findOrFail($id);
```

this returns the formatted data similar to these (it's an example):

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "jhon",
  "email": "jhon@gmail.com",
  "created_at": "2018-09-14 12:07:35",
  "updated_at": "2018-09-14 12:07:38",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "description": "task description",
      "person_id": 1,
      "created_at": "2018-09-18 21:07:48",
      "updated_at": "2018-09-19 20:47:37",
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "description": "task description",
      "person_id": 1,
      "created_at": "2018-09-19 00:15:45",
      "updated_at": "2018-09-20 15:28:58",
    }
  ],
  "posts": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "post title",
      "person_id": 1,
      "created_at": "2018-09-14 12:08:52",
      "updated_at": "2018-09-14 16:21:03"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "title": "post title",
      "person_id": 1,
      "created_at": "2018-09-17 18:33:51",
      "updated_at": "2018-09-17 18:33:51"
    }
  ]
}
```

my question is this: is it possible to separate the result of the tasks and posts models in a different array, if this is possible as I should do ?, I want to have a result like this:

```
[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "description": "task description",
      "person_id": 1,
      "created_at": "2018-09-18 21:07:48",
      "updated_at": "2018-09-19 20:47:37",
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "description": "task description",
      "person_id": 1,
      "created_at": "2018-09-19 00:15:45",
      "updated_at": "2018-09-20 15:28:58",
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "post title",
      "person_id": 1,
      "created_at": "2018-09-14 12:08:52",
      "updated_at": "2018-09-14 16:21:03"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "title": "post title",
      "person_id": 1,
      "created_at": "2018-09-17 18:33:51",
      "updated_at": "2018-09-17 18:33:51"
    }
 ]
```

Comment: `Task::where("person_id", $id)->get();`?

Comment: Are you returning a JSON response?

Comment: yes as the example

Comment: Something like `$person->merged = $person->tasks->toBase()->merge($person->posts);`?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir it seems that this works, a question: what happens if I have one or two more models, I can continue using merge, is it possible? and advisable to do this?

Comment: Apply it to all models: `foreach($persons as $person) { [...] }`

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = DB:table('posts')->get();
$b = DB:table('tasks')->get();
$c = array_merge($a,$b);
```

see doc:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries